# Split facet_wrap panel when x is a factor in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a vertical line to split `facet_wrap` panel in ggplot2.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, hwy))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour = drv))+
  facet_wrap(~year)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

my question is how could we add vertical lines when x is a **factor**?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?scale_x_discrete`:

> You can use continuous positions even with a discrete position scale -
>   this allows you (e.g.) to place labels between bars in a bar chart.

You can add vertical lines with `geom_vline()` & set the position at 1.5, 2.5, etc:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour = drv))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(1.5, 2.5), linetype = "dashed") +
  facet_wrap(~ year) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much,Lin!